# wget is not able to fetch 4 level directory using --include

Tags: bash, wget

Right now i am trying to create a script. In which, downloading a set of directories based on input.

For example -

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=2 --no-parent --reject "index.html*" \
    --include-directories 'apache/hadoop/common/'           \
    http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/hadoop/
```

This is working fine.

But when i am trying to add one more level to my path from `apache/hadoop/common/` to `apache/hadoop/common/current/`.

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=2 --no-parent --reject "index.html*" \
    --include-directories 'apache/hadoop/common/current/'   \
    http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/hadoop/
```

It's not working.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Comment: This is impossible to tell without more information. What the two URLs you're using?

Comment: @jww Don't you consider shell scripting as a programming language?

Comment: @darnir Updated question with example.

Comment: Guys, can you please give the reason, why you have downvoted the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the URL you are downloading from. Try this:

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=2 --no-parent --reject "index.html*" \
    --include-directories 'apache/hadoop/common/current/'   \
    http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/hadoop/common/current
```

The reason why your original command didn't work is because wget downloads `http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/hadoop/index.html` which contains:

```
<html>
<head><title>Index of /apache/hadoop/</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /apache/hadoop/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="common/">common/</a>                                            20-Nov-2018 03:24                   -
<a href="core/">core/</a>                                              20-Nov-2018 03:24                   -
<a href="ozone/">ozone/</a>                                             19-Nov-2018 20:22                   -
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

wget looks at all of the links in that file, which are:

```
/apache
/apache/hadoop/common
/apache/hadoop/core
/apache/hadoop/ozone
```

None of those links match the  `--include-directories 'apache/hadoop/common/current/'` argument, so it exits.

Comment: This is interesting. According to your answer, i have to change my source itself. Is there any other way?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.